# No route matches [POST] "/login"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, simple-form

When I submit this form

```
<h1>Log In</h1>

<%= simple_form_for sessions_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %>
    <%= f.submit 'Log In' %>
<% end %>
```

It gives me this error: `No route matches [POST] "/login"`. It is true that I don't have a route that matches that, but from what I understand, it should be `POST`ing to `sessions#create`, for which I have a route and an action. Why is it not doing this?

**routes.rb**

```
DinnerDash::Application.routes.draw do
    get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
    get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
    get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'

    root 'items#index'

    resources :users
    resources :password_resets
    resources :sessions
    resources :items

    get "password/Resets"
    get "password/create"
    get "password/edit"
    get "password/update"
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = login(params[:email], params[:password], params[:remember_me])
        if user
            redirect_back_or_to root_url, notice: 'Logged in!'
        else
            flash.now.alert = 'Unable to login.'
            render :new
        end
    end

    def destroy
        logout
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged out.'
    end
end
```

**rake routes**

It's sorta hard to read, but the important points are that there's a `GET /login`, not a `POST /login`, and there's a `GET` and `POST` for `/sessions_path`.

```
login_path   GET     /login(.:format)    sessions#new
logout_path  GET     /logout(.:format)   sessions#destroy
signup_path  GET     /signup(.:format)   users#new
root_path    GET     /   items#index
users_path   GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
POST     /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path    GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path   GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path    GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT  /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
password_resets_path     GET     /password_resets(.:format)  password_resets#index
POST     /password_resets(.:format)  password_resets#create
new_password_reset_path  GET     /password_resets/new(.:format)  password_resets#new
edit_password_reset_path     GET     /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
password_reset_path  GET     /password_resets/:id(.:format)  password_resets#show
PATCH    /password_resets/:id(.:format)  password_resets#update
PUT  /password_resets/:id(.:format)  password_resets#update
DELETE   /password_resets/:id(.:format)  password_resets#destroy
sessions_path    GET     /sessions(.:format)     sessions#index
POST     /sessions(.:format)     sessions#create
new_session_path     GET     /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
edit_session_path    GET     /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)    sessions#edit
session_path     GET     /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#show
PATCH    /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#update
PUT  /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#update
DELETE   /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
items_path   GET     /items(.:format)    items#index
POST     /items(.:format)    items#create
new_item_path    GET     /items/new(.:format)    items#new
edit_item_path   GET     /items/:id/edit(.:format)   items#edit
item_path    GET     /items/:id(.:format)    items#show
PATCH    /items/:id(.:format)    items#update
PUT  /items/:id(.:format)    items#update
DELETE   /items/:id(.:format)    items#destroy
password_Resets_path     GET     /password/Resets(.:format)  password#Resets
password_create_path     GET     /password/create(.:format)  password#create
password_edit_path   GET     /password/edit(.:format)    password#edit
password_update_path     GET     /password/update(.:format)  password#update
```

Comment: What is the result of `rake routes`?

Comment: @bobbystouket I posted `rake routes` as an edit to the question. It's sorta hard to read, but the important points are that there's a `GET /login`, not a `POST /login`, and there's a `GET` and `POST` for `/sessions_path`.

Comment: It doesn't look like your `simple_form_for` is wrapping a model object. The first argument should be a `@user` or something.

Comment: @pdobb Right, it isn't wrapping a model object. Does it have to?

Comment: I don't think it actually has to wrap a model, but it needs something there, other than a path (like a symbol!). @deep's answer looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= simple_form_for :session, :url => sessions_path do |f| %>
  # rest of the form
<% end %>
```

Comment: `:method => :post` is likely superfluous.

Comment: That basically works. Thanks! It's missing the `do |f|` part, and I had to change `params[:email]` to `params[:session][:email]`.

Comment: @pdobb `:method => :post` is indeed superfluous.

Comment: Updated answer to include `do |f|` and remove `:method => :post`

Comment: @pdobb Thanks for the edit I forgot to include do |f| part :)